# Vim and NERDTree - remap Enter functionality

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I'm trying to remap my <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> combo into the NERDTree <kbd>Enter</kbd> functionality. Let me explain: when I navigate files/folders inside NERDTree, I can open files/expand folders with <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I want to do this with a left-hand key combination like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>. I tried to remap those keys to `<CR>` and to `<Enter>`, both none of them worked:

```
# in ~/.vimrc
nnoremap ≈ <Enter>     " doesn't work
nnoremap ≈ <CR>        " doesn't work
nnoremap ≈ <CR><Enter> " doesn't work
```

When I say "doesn't work", I mean that when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> while exploring files/folders, I move to the next file/folder (which I guess it's like moving to the next line).

*Note* I'm on a Mac, so `≈` is actually the output from <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> (it's tested with other mappings).

What should I remap?

Comment: This works for me on my mac. What is the exact line you have in your vimrc. (I am assuming the lines you have above are not the lines you have because of the comments)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modifiers with <kbd>Alt</kbd> (`<M-` or `<A-`) is troublesome in a lot of environments, especially in terminals over SSH with a terminal multiplexer, and I therefore try not to use it. Even if I do get it to work on my desktop, it might not work somewhere else for some obscure reason. There's plenty of keybinds to take from. Unless you have a big reason to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>, I'd advice against it.

---

That being said you can find which command is being invoked when pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or <kbd>o</kbd>) to open a folder in NERDTree using the `:verb` command. This has to be run while the NERDTree pane is selected:

```
:verb map <Enter>
n  o           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("o")<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/key_map.vim
```

Now that you the correct command there's no point in hacking with rebinding something else to `<Enter>` or `<CR>`.
Generally you'd use `<A-x>`, but if `≈` works for you then that's fine I guess:

```
:nnoremap ≈ :call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("o")<CR>
```

**Bottom line:**
I would like to note that I don't see why you would want to use such a mapping. You can use <kbd>o</kbd>, and you would/should be in close range of this (same could be said for <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Comment: That works like a charm. Thanks! Speaking about using `Alt`, I noted what you said and I'll try to fix all my `Alt-` shortcuts as soon as I can. Thanks again!

Comment: @whatyouhide No problemo! Glad to see that my writeup was of any help other than just giving you the command :-)

Comment: @timss Thank you very much for :verb map <Enter>